# Spring webflux: flatmap asynchronous transformation

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have read that flatmap transformation is asynchronous, here in the example I am printing the name of thread inside the lambda definition. It is printing the same thread in which the source has been subscribed. As per my understanding it should print a different thread name - other than in which source has been subscribed, as this transformation must be performed in different thread.

```java
Flux.just(1, -2, 3, 4, -5, 6)
    .flatMap(element -> { 
        try { 
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } 
        catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        } 

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " element: " + element); 
        return Flux.just(element);
    })
    .subscribe()
```

Answer (score 2):

The fact it's *asynchronous* doesn't necessarily imply that it runs in *parallel*, which you seem to be expecting here. However, you can convert the `Flux` into a `ParallelFlux` and specify a parallel scheduler:

```
Flux.just(1, -2, 3, 4, -5, 6)
        .parallel()
        .runOn(Schedulers.elastic())
        .flatMap(element
                -> {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                    + " element: " + element);

            return Flux.just(element);
        })
        .subscribe();
Thread.currentThread().join(); //Just a hack to keep the program alive.
```

If, on the other hand you don't want it to run in parallel, but just on a separate thread to your main thread, then no need to convert it to a parallel `Flux` - just provide a `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())` call or similar instead.

Comment: Thank you for answer. This is clear to me if I will be executing something in different thread that doesn't mean it will be executed paralleIly.  My confusion is if I am saying I am executing a task asynchronously , doesn't that mean I need to  create a separate thread for execution of that task? If it is yes, then when the lambda would be passed into the flatmap(), that lambda should be executed in different thread not necessarily parallelly it could be concurrent. But its executing thread should be different.

Comment: "Asynchronous", loosely speaking, just means that it'll do something in the background, and fire a callback when done. The *thread* it uses to do something in the background can be any that you specify - it can be in the same thread or a separate one. Working in the same thread doesn't make much sense in this scenario where you're blocking the thread, but in real world use, you may (for instance) want to fire a http request. That, if written asynchronously, wouldn't block the thread - so you could still sensibly use the main thread in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't print a different thread name. Reactive by default runs on a single threads - on which the subscription happens. In this case, the subscription happens on the calling thread, hence, all the elements are emitted on it and processed further on it.

Let us first try to understand how .`flatMap` works:

1. For each upstream event, you create a stream out of it.
2. `flatMap` subscribes to each inner stream eagerly (that's why they are even triggered). Note that eagerly here means it subscribes to all the inner streams at once, without waiting for other inner streams to complete (unlike `concatMap`).
3. Does a dynamic merge of all the inner stream, as they emit events.

Note that each inner stream is after all, a stream. Unless you tell it to use a different thread, each will emit on the same thread (the calling thread, what's happening in your case). You can do a `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic)` (or `schedulers.parallel()`) for each one of them, if you want to process them in parallel:

```
Flux.just(1, -2, 3, 4, -5, 6)
    .flatMap(
        element -> {
          //this will always print the same thread - the calling thread basically
          System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " element: " + element);
          return Mono.just(element)
              .subscribeOn(Schedulers.parallel())
              .doOnNext(
                  a ->
                      System.out.println(
                          a + " emitted on thread: " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));
        })
    .subscribe();
```

.`flatMap` doesn't care what thread an element comes in, and what thread it goes out - all it will do is subscribe to the inner streams and merge their events as and when they comes. Remember that each of the inner streams is a 'promise'. It will complete ultimately (with a `onComplete`) signal, but you don't know when. `flatMap` still doesn't care. `concatMap`, however, waits for a stream to complete before subscribing to the next. That's how it maintains the order of the original stream.

Read more on this here (my own article on flatMap):

https://medium.com/swlh/understanding-reactors-flatmap-operator-a6a7e62d3e95

Answer (score 0):

The use of `flatMap` doesn't affect the thread on which it executes.  You can use `subscribeOn` to influence the Thread on which the execution will occur:

```
        Flux.just(1, -2, 3, 4, -5, 6)
                .flatMap(element ->
                {
                    try { Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() +
                            " element: " + element);
                    return Flux.just(element);
                })
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
                .subscribe();
```

Depending on what you want the behaviour to be you can make use of any of the following - 
`Schedulers.elastic()`, `Schedulers.single()`, `Schedulers.parallel()`, `Schedulers.immeadiate()`